# How to make BIND return old cached enties if all forwarders are failed?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, cache

I have a local forwarding BIND server installed at localhost. In its configuration there is a couple of forwarders:

options { ... forwarders { 1.2.3.4; 5.6.7.8; }; ... };

Servers which are pointed by "forwarders" hold zones with TTL=60 seconds.

Sometimes all these forwarders are inaccessible. If it happens, in 60 seconds localhost's BIND also stops to respond queries with "Temporary failure in name resolution" error.

The question is: how to make the localhost's BIND respond to locally cached queries even if cached entries are expired and all forwarders are dead? Because it's much better to respond with an outdated response than not to respond at all.

Comment: For security reasons, it is *not* better to respond with an outdated response.

Comment: In my case it's definitely better, because servers referred by "forwarders" section support internal zones mostly (cluster machine's directory). But sometimes datacenters lose connectivity (or DNS machine inside the same datacenter could break suddenly).

Comment: wait - why are they inaccessible for so long?  increase the ttl to however long they may be inaccessible for.  B) put up some backup so they are always accessible - dyn dnsmadeeasy etc?